# How to execute getPath with Spectron?

Tags: node.js, electron, spectron

Inside my Electron application I use `remote.app.getPath('documents'` to get the path of the users current documents directory. I also use Spectron and would like to access this directory inside my test.

What is the best way to execute this function within my Spectron test?

Unfortunately `remote.app` is undefined, therefore not available, and also the `Application` itself doesn't have any function.

```
test.beforeEach(async (t) => {
  (t.context as any).app = new spectron.Application({
    path: electronPath,
    args: [appPath]
  });

  // how to call getPath here?

  return (t.context as any).app.start();
});
```

Comment: Any progress on this? I have similar problem.

Comment: I made a seperate file and included it in the test directly, so I don't go through `remote.app`